# LLDB crashes on raspberry pi

Tags: c++11, raspberry-pi3, lldb

I have a c++ program running "fine" but when I try to debug it with LLDB, LLDB just quits on me.

```
Process ... launching
Segmentation fault
```

Even if I set a breakpoint on the very first line in main I just get these two lines. Googling yields the typical memory leak errors in user code. I don't think that's the case here since my program runs outside of LLDB.

I am not experiencing any issues under ubuntu. Could it be related to ARM (raspberry pi)?

Answer (score 1):

You might have more luck sending a query about the state of the lldb port to raspberry pi on the lldb-dev mailing list.  Details here:

http://lists.llvm.org/mailman/listinfo/lldb-dev